# External FQDN for RDS server? or sub-domain?

Tags: subdomain, windows-terminal-services, rds, fqdn

I am trying to setup a terminal server and need to have an external FQDN name.

So far we have a main domain name hosted by 3rd party. lets call it "aaa.com"

We also have subdomain name called "mail.aaa.com", "vpn.aaa.com", now I need to have a subdomain name called "rds.aaa.com".

My question is that this "rds.aaa.com" need to be hosted externally through the hosting company again or we can setup this "rds.aaa.com" internally? I dont know how people setup "mail.aaa.com" and "vpn.aaa.com" before.

I contacted with our hosting provider for "aaa.com", the told me that we dont have to host a new "rds.aaa.com" with them, just create a subdomain internally. but they wont tell me how....

What are the steps for setup this FQDN subdomain name for RDS server.

Comment: By `external` I assume you mean `public`. If that's the case then you need to add the record to the name server(s) that are authoritative for your external/public DNS zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your nameserver/s that is/are responsible for the aaa.com domain and add an A record there. It doesn't have to be your hosting provider, may be that's why they can't help you further.

You have to find it out yourself where you have your domain registered and which nameservers it is using. In most cases you are supposed to have an account to a control panel for your nameservers, where you can make necessary entries.

I strongly suggest that, you take a little time to read and understand the concept of Nameservers, hosting etc and how these all works.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service

Comment: Thanks, just found out all information I needed and had a sub-domain name created. Thanks